# React router path not changing when typed in URL

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, create-react-app, react-router-dom

Index.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <App/>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

App.js

```
    <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/referral/:referralcode" component={Referral} />
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <Route exact path="/password_reset" component={PasswordReset} />
                    <Route exact path="/create_new_account" component={CreateNewAccount} />
                    <Route exact path="/verification_code" component={VerificationCode} />
                    <Route exact path="/account" component={Account} />
                </Switch>
```

```
    "react": "^16.8.1",
"react-dom": "^16.8.1",
"react-router": "^5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "2.1.3",
```

when I manually type in the URL to another path besides "/login" I get redirected back to the login page. This was built with create-react-app

Comment: Looks like the components redirect to the `/login` page if the user isn't authenticated. Can you share a [CodeSandbox](http://codesandbox.io/) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Yes thanks! I didn't realize in the code history. push was being called if the user wasn't authenticated